# Problem with double click on title bar or right click on it or Any window washed out and disappear in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, 13.10, 14.04, compiz

I run over the following problem in *Ubuntu 14.04*:

When I right click, or double click title bar of a nautilus, or at any opened window, or any browser window and so on, it shade and disappear.

Image is an Example of behavior of terminal window when right/double clicked:

[image: example]

In the previous Ubuntu versions (13.10) when a title bar right-click cause the menu to pop-up. Appears a sub-menu with options to move the window around work spaces and few more choices.
Now I can not find this menu, and this option can be reached only with shortcut keys.

I wold be glad to have a hint of that issue.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can tweak title-bar actions by using **Unity Tweak Tool** as following.

open terminal and run `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`command to install.

Then goto **Window Manager > Additional** Tab and Set **Title-bar Actions**.

[image]

**Set
Double click: Maximize
Right click: Menu**

---

If you choose **command-line** method then open terminal and type following:

To **get** current settings for title-bar actions:-

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-double-click-titlebar
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-right-click-titlebar
```

To **set** new settings title-bar actions:-

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-double-click-titlebar 'toggle-maximize'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-right-click-titlebar menu
```

This worked for me. Hope this helps.

Comment: the shade is so strage, if I click minimize it will have identical functionality; I was expecting it to just roll up, so keep just the title bar; unfortunately that functionality seems to have been completely removed?

Answer (score 0):

Happens to me too running Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit and Nvidia drivers from repository. However, on a netbook with a Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit and intel drivers it doesn't happen and the behaviour is normal.

Edit: Following the lead of previous answer, I found that my settings in windows manager were, in fact, different on my computers. The thing is that I made some compiz and unity resets on the first computer and the default values on Window Manager > Additional set all mouse clicks to "window shade" or "roll up" feature. Default values should perhaps be changed. Because there is no point having the same feature atributted to all 3 mouse buttons and, in addition, "window shade" is buggy and not working in Ubuntu 14.04 as described here:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1293740